# Dbeaver icon is blurry on MAC

Tags: macos, icons, dbeaver

When you run Dbeaver on Mac and the application loads. The ICON in the DOCK becomes blurry. As if its very low quality.  Any way to fix it?

No! the refresh of the DOCK icons does not help. Its picking up the running ICON from somewhere else in the package.

Answer (score 1):

The solution i found is this:

go to

//Dbeaver/DBeaver.app/Contents/Eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/82/0/.cp/icons

Rename the old dbeaver.png to dbeaver-old.png and add the new high quality png with the same name.

Comment: It works, thanks. The only difference is that in my installation the folder was "org.eclipse.osgi/95/0/.cp/icons/dbeaver48.png".